# problem using fprintf

Tags: c, file, printf

I'm trying to print to a text file numerous variables yet it doesn't work.
I checked and verified that i write it in the correct syntax.
I also checked the return value and it's positive therefore i know it did write to the file, however when i open the file it's empty.

I would be happy for some help.
This is the code:

I initiate DynsaleDayPtr in the main:

```
FILE* DynsaleDayPtr = CreateTextFiles("sale_day.txt");
```

Create function:

```
FILE* CreateTextFiles (char* fileName)  
{  
    FILE* saleFilePtr=NULL;  

    if((saleFilePtr=fopen(fileName,"a+"))==NULL)  
        printf("File couldn't be opened\n");  
    return saleFilePtr;  
}
```

The call to the function TextAddSale is done from a function that is called in the main:
`TextAddSale(DynSaleDayPtr,dynNumOfRecords);`

```
Bool TextAddSale (FILE* DynsaleDayPtr, int* dynNumOfRecords)  
{  

    char id[6];  
    char name [50];  
    char priceChar[20];  
    char* tmp = NULL;  
    int price=-1;  
    DynamicRecord * newRec=NULL;  

    scanf("%s%s%s",id,name,priceChar);

    newRec = (DynamicRecord *)malloc(sizeof(DynamicRecord));  
    if (newRec == NULL)  
        return False;  
    tmp = (char*)malloc(strlen(name)+1);  
    if (tmp == NULL)  
    {  
        free (newRec);  
        return False;  
    }  
    strcpy(tmp,name);  
    newRec->productName = tmp;  
    strcpy(newRec->productId, id);  
    newRec->productPrice=atoi (priceChar);  

    if (fprintf(DynsaleDayPtr,"%d %s %s %d", strlen(newRec->productName),  
    newRec->productId, newRec->productName, newRec->productPrice)>0)  
    {  
        *dynNumOfRecords=(*dynNumOfRecords)+1;  
        return True;  
    }  
}
```

thanks!

Comment: What is `DynsaleDayPtr` ? I don't see it declared anywhere.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing it, but where are you opening the file?

Comment: Did you close the file after writing your record(s) to it? When you say you opened it and found it empty, do you mean that you looked at it with a text editor or something, or that your code `fopen`ed it and tried to read from it?

Comment: Please post a (reduced version of a) compilable program that exhibits the issue.

Comment: Did you close or flush? The output might be buffered.

Comment: DynsaleDayPtr is a pointer to a text file i've opened outside of the function and sent it as a parameter to the function i've posted (i edited changes above). i didn't close the file or flushed.
and i indeed opened the file with a notepad not "fopen"

Comment: trying flushing the stream and ultimately closing it and tell us what happens

Answer (score 1):

You need to flush the stream.

```
fflush(FILE*);
```

Of course, you have to close the stream if you have done with it.

```
fclose(FILE*);
```

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @pmg - try something like this:

```
FILE *pFile = fopen("foo.txt","w");
if (pFile==NULL)
   bad();
fprintf(pfile,"Hello world\n");
fclose(pfile);
```

make that work first - then fix whatever's wrong in the big app -

Answer (score 0):

A thought:

```
scanf("%s%s%s",id,name,priceChar);
```

the above statement is a bit dodgy since you haven't said how many bytes
should go in each string.

better to use fgets() then parse the string retrieving the individual values
or create a better format specifier.

If the above statement causes a memory overwrite the rest of your program
could malfunction causing things like what you describe.

Answer (score 0):

`fprintf()` most likely uses buffered output. Therefore, you should either `fflush()` the `DynSaleDayPtr` stream or, better yet, print a newline to the file. The latter has the added benefit of making the file contents actually readable...

Also, don't forget to `close()` the stream when you're finished with writing. This will also render `fflush()` unnecessary.

Comment: Writing a newline to the file will only cause it to be flushed if it's been set as line-buffered. This is not the case by default after `fopen`; you'd need to call `setvbuf` to make it happen. (I forget exactly what the standard says about the default buffer mode -- I *think* it says that `fopen` gives you block buffering by default -- but it certainly doesn't guarantee that files are line-buffered.)